# Hay alternativas para la función shift en Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estoy intentando crear una función que busca en una determinada columna cambios según dos condiciones, por lo que se usa la función shift; sin embargo, cuando se aplica la función en una columna de números floats, me detecta un error.

```
def indices_falla(df, umbral, prom, i):
            try:
                condicion1 = df[i] > umbral.max() if umbral.max() > 0.1 else 0.1 #Se establece la condición que se evaluará entre cada corriente de la fase especificada del df y la maxima corriente dentro de la serie de corrientes maximas
                condicion2 = df[i] > prom.mean() if prom.mean() > 0.1 else 0.1
                condicion = condicion1 and condicion2
                grupos = (condicion != condicion.shift()).cumsum() #Se comparan los elementos y se hace una suma acumulativa    
                primeros_indices = df[condicion].groupby(grupos).apply(lambda group: group.index[0]) #Se agrupa los indices donde la condición se cumple            
                listFalla = primeros_indices.values.tolist() #Convertir los índices a una lista
                
            except Exception as e:
                print('No se detecta falla', e)
                listFalla=[]
            return listFalla
```

El error que me sale en pantalla es: "No se detecta falla 'float' object has no attribute 'shift'"
¿Alguien tiene conocimiento de como puedo mejorar esta función?

Comment: Hola Alejo, para aclarar, ¿podrías explicar que esperas de `df[i] > umbral.max() if umbral.max() > 0.1 else 0.1` y que es `umbral` (el tipo de dato)? Si `umbral` es una serie de pandas o un array de numpy, `max` retorna un solo valor, si es > 0.1, dicho valor se comprueba por cada item de `df[i]`, retornando una serie de boleanos. Si `max` es menor de 0.1 **no** se retorna una serie de boleanos, sino un float (0.1), es decir, `codicion1` sera 0.1 que no tiene lógicamente el método `shift`...

Comment: Aun si se retorna una serie en ambos casos (max y mean > 0.1), tendrás otro error en `condicion1 and condicion2` por otra razón (`ValueError: The truth value of a series is ambiguous` si mal no recuerdo). Seria muy positivo que agregaras un ejemplo de entrada para la función con unos cuantos datos nada mas y la salida que esperas para esos datos.